# Spectral decomposition of a specific operator

Tags: differential-equations, differential-operators

To understand a crucial example in representation theory, I need the explicit spectral decomposition of the differential operator 
$$
Df(x)=(1+x^2)f''(x)+2xf'(x)
$$ on $L^2({\mathbb R})$. I'm not an expert, but at first glance, theory tells me the existence of a spectral measure, but not what it looks like. Is the spectral measure absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure? What are the multiplicities? Has it been explicitly computed somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Sturm-Liouville operator $(Df)(x)=(pf')'$, with $p=1+x^2$. These can be rewritten as Schrodinger equations, by using what I would call a Kummer-Liouville transformation. By some conspiracy, all reference to these on the internet seems to have disappeared, but see perhaps my answer [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204538/uniform-boundedness-of-eigenfunctions-of-an-elementary-differential-operator/204606#204606)

We introduce the new variables $t=\int_0^x p^{-1/2}(s)\, ds$, $u=p^{1/4}f$, and then $-D$ becomes the Schrodinger operator
$$
Lu = - \frac{d^2u}{dt^2} + V(t)u , \quad V= \frac{p''}{4} - \frac{p'^2}{16p} .
$$
That gives
$$
V = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4(1+x^2)} = \frac{1}{4} + O( e^{-|t|}) .
$$
Since this is almost constant, with a rapidly decaying error term, standard results show that we have purely absolutely continuous spectrum of multiplicity $2$ on $\sigma_{ac}(-D)=[1/4, \infty)$, and some (non-empty, finite) discrete spectrum below $1/4$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get these results. Can you check for errors or typos?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your computations and I get different results.

Comment: @Corbennick: The formulae look correct to me. You did notice that I'm discussing $-D$, not $D$ ? In particular, when working out $d^2 u/dt^2$, the term $(pf')'$ (with $'=d/dx$) must be set equal to $-\lambda f$.

Comment: I am still not getting it. Let's split it into two steps. First let $f(x)=h(t(x))$, then the operator becomes $h''(t)+\frac{p'(x(t))}{p(x)^{1/2}}h'(t)$. The second step would by multiplying $h$ by $p(x)^{1/4}$. BUt, as you already have coefficient 1 with $h''$, you won't get that coefficient with $u''$. Also, I don't get cancellation of the $u'$ term. It seems I am misinterpreting your solution completely.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the problem was in my calculations. However, it turned out that my calculations were alright, only I interpreted them wrongly.